# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500 Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am developing a application in which i have a post request to get data from server.Even i have checked my CORS plugin and parameters. Using Postman this api works fine but using angular 2 i am getting error. Here is my code for http request:

```
    let relatedVideo = this.http.postRequests('pages/relatedVideo.json', {video_id:videoid});
        relatedVideo.subscribe((vdata:any)=>{
        console.log(vdata);
    })
```

my other api's are working properly but this one cause error. Here below i have mentioned error returned:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/pages/relatedVideo.json. 

Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
next @ application_ref.js:359
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:331
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:292
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:59 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:59
next @ application_ref.js:359
schedulerFn @ async.js:93
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:331
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:292
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
error_handler.js:60 TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:73)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:61)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:128)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:102)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onError (xhr_backend.js:95)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:275)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:262)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:274)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:151)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:345)
```

Sorry for my english...

Comment: when using potman you will not detect CORS issues, that only happens when you are sending requests from inside a webpage in a different domain. generally, it looks like the problem is in the server.  did you allow CORS requests in your server? did you check what request was received in the server?

Comment: my other api's are working properly expect this. My other api's are also on the same server they don't behave like this and actually post is not working for this api call.

Comment: you didnt answer any of my questions, and i cant really understand if you got an error to postman or not. I dont see any way I could help you, maybe someone else will. good luck